# How to replace cart item product permalink in Woocommerce cart

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to replace a product permalink in the cart, i.e. we don't want to back to the product but rather a page. I basically loop through the cart and is the product category is subscription, then I want to change the permalink.

I have written some code that should work, but it doesn't, it works fine if I have only one product, but as soon as I have more than one, my code just makes everything the same and I just can't figure out why.

```
function change_sub_url( $product_title, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) 
{

    $category = array('Subscription');
    $replacement_permalink = 'https://THE_URL/subscriptions/';

    // Cart page check 
    if ( is_cart() ) 
    {
        // Get Cart of the user //
        $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
        foreach ( $cart as $cart_key => $cart_item )
        {
            $return_value="";
            $_product = $cart_item['data'] ;
            $product_permalink = $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '';

            // Check for product categories we're looking for Subscription
            if ( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) 
                {
                    // It will return the product name on the cart page.
                    // As the filter used on checkout and cart are same.     
                    $return_value = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $replacement_permalink ), $_product->get_title()); 
                    return $return_value;
                }

            $return_value = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_title());
            return $return_value ; 
        }   
    }
}

add_filter ('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'change_sub_url' , 10, 3 );
```

This code should change the links only where the category is subscription. I am sure I am missing something super simple.

Thanks for your Help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `woocommerce_cart_item_permalink` filter hook is the simpler and dedicated way to get what you want, with the following compact and effective code:

```
add_filter ('woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', 'custom_cart_item_permalink' , 10, 3 );
function custom_cart_item_permalink( $permalink, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    // HERE your defined product category
    $category = array('Subscription');

    if ( is_cart() && has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        $permalink = 'https://THE_URL/subscriptions/';
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Hi Loic, thanks so much for the answer, I really appreciate your help. I have tested the code and it works perfectly .
Thank You.

Comment: @KeithHill Good! It was something easy, when you know WooCommerce hooks.

Comment: how to edit product permalink in cart and remove some slug items in it?